# Processing a large csv files with pandas in a faster way

Tags: python, pandas

I have a task of reading two large csv files (~5 millions of records, ~2Gig) every day and to process the intersecting and non-intersecting columns in different ways (which is irrelevant to the question). The problem I am facing is that the files are taking more time to load, but once they are loaded (via read_csv(..)), the processing takes just a few seconds. I am wondering:

1. if I can improve the **read_csv(..)** time which btw skips both *header* and *footer* and has *multi-char* separator

   - `pd.read_csv(input_file, sep='\x1D', engine='python', skiprows=1, skipfooter=1, header=0, dtype=str, keep_default_na=False)`
   - *Note*: the 'dtype=str' is to ensure pandas don't manipulate anything (i.e., rounding of fractions, inferring absolute num as float, etc.)
   - *Note2*: I cannot load these CSVs in chunks as that would make finding the intersecting rows between two CSVs very harder and time consuming.
2. Is there a way I can do this operation in a lesser RAM-sized system since I kept increasing the RAM in my current system whenever the app throws the "MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.11 GiB for an array with shape (118, 8140983)..." error.

Comment: I recommend to look into Polars: https://pola.rs. This is much faster, and there also exist `scan_csv` methods to reduce memory overhead. In my experience this is just as easy as Pandas.

Comment: If you have control over the generation of files, try to save data in parquet format instead of csv. Reading from parquet format is faster.

Comment: @sdawar, I don't. but can I convert to parquet format and back into csv after processing?

Comment: @OlafdeL, Polar has limitations such as it can't have a separator more than a single byte (which is needed in our case because of '\x1D' separator)

Comment: The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html) seems complete, not much more that you can try

Comment: @SpaceyBot, question: Where are you getting the csv from, is there a specific team which supplies you with csv? Can you request them to send you parquet instead of csv?

Comment: another team, yes. but they can only output in csv, no way they can change this

Comment: @SpaceyBot, as people have commented before you can go for polars. You can also check [dask](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/glossary/dask/) which can be used for processing large datasets.

Comment: as with Polars, Dask also does not yet support [multi-indexes](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1493).

Answer (score -3):

We can optimize loading of large csv's as per use cases:

1. use selective columns to improve performance and reduce memory consuptions
2. Use chunk or loop
3. modin module to use multiple cores